# Select items that have never been ordered using the MINUS operator

Tags: oracle, minus

I have the following two tables:

```
ITEM (Item#, Item_Name, Unit_Price)

ORDER_ITEM (Order#, Item#, Qty)
```

Now, how do I list the items that have never been ordered by using the MINUS operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
select item# from item
minus
select item# from ORDER_ITEM
```

Comment: Yeah that can work ..... However, I was interested to display Item_Name instead of Item# by using MINUS operator.

Comment: select * from item where item# in (select item# from item
minus
select item# from ORDER_ITEM)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long to add as a comment to @CalZ answer so I create another answer:

```
select item#, Item_Name from item
minus 
select i.item#, i.Item_Name 
from item i
join order_item oi
    on i.item# = oi.item#
```

in the second leg of the minus, we construct a new relation using a join between item and order_item that we can subtract from item.

Comment: That seems like an unnecessary join and it would be better to use the list of items to select from the item table.

Comment: @JoeW why is it unnecessary? How could we get `Item_Name` without a join to `item`?

Comment: By using the return from the selects with the minus as input into another select. I might be wrong but it seems like it would be faster to just do a direct select then to do the join since you wont be selecting a lot of duplicate data from the item table.. Using the comment from CalZ on the other answer seems faster. select * from item where item# in (select item# from item minus select item# from ORDER_ITEM)

Comment: @JoeW so it would still be one join. But different order of logical execution (minus vs join). I don'tknow enough about Oracle and whether one or the other would be more efficient. or whether Oracle optimizer knows to rewrite the 2 versions/ways.

Comment: If the order table is 100+ times as large as the item table do you think the work to join the item table in during the initial select is going to be the same as using the results to select from the item table?

Comment: @JoeW, in theory, the DBMS can rewrite the query anyway it like as long as it is logically equivalent. When I wrote the answer it did not have the Oracle tag, like ybercube I don't know Oracle well enough to judge how it would evaluate the query. Anyhow, I assumed that this was some kind of assignment so it is probably of some use to see different ways to express the same query.